# Error in Client Server Application : Unable to find converter for java.util.UUID

Tags: java, client-server, httpclient, uuid, restlet

I am working on a client server application. I was using Restlet 2.0.3. Due to a heavy load task my client was getting timed-out. I searched on the forum and found that switching over to Restlet 2.2 would help. So I did that. I upgraded my Restlet to 2.2.1. But now my code has stopped working at precisely this method.

```
public synchronized UUID generateUniqueSessionId(String userAtDomain)
    {
        UUID newSessionId = UUID.randomUUID();
        SessionAttributes sessionAttributes = new SessionAttributes();
        sessionAttributes.setAlive(true);
        sessionAttributes.setFQUserName(userAtDomain);
        loggedInUsers.put(newSessionId, sessionAttributes);
        return newSessionId;
    }
```

So I am returning the UUID at last. 
This code is on the server and invoked during login. Following is the error that I am getting from the logs.

**16 Mar 2015 11:23:18  WARN - Unable to find a converter for this object : f3d2edda-443c-454d-856a-fb4e7ed9c535**

And this object referred in the log belongs to java.util.UUID

The code on the client side which invokes the server looks like this.

```
public UUID authenticateUser(String username, String passwd) {

        try {
            String url = RESTLetWebSvcsFactory.getFactoryInstance().getServer_URL() + "login/" + username + "/" + passwd;

            Context context = new Context();

            Client client = new Client(context, Protocol.HTTP);
            ClientHelper helper = new ClientHelper(client);
            helper.getHelpedParameters().set("socketConnectTimeoutMs", "60000");

            ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(url);
            LoginLogoutResource resource = cr.wrap(LoginLogoutResource.class);
            return resource.loginUser();
        } catch (ResourceException re) {
            if (re.getStatus().isConnectorError()) {
                try {
                    RESTLetWebSvcsFactory.enableFallBackServer();
                    String url = RESTLetWebSvcsFactory.getFactoryInstance().getServer_URL() + "login/" + username + "/" + passwd;
                    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(url);
                    LoginLogoutResource resource = cr.wrap(LoginLogoutResource.class);
                    return resource.loginUser();
                } catch (ResourceException re1) {
                    int statusCode = new RESTLetErrorHandler().handleServerError(re);
                    if (statusCode != -1) {
                        throw new UserCRUDException(statusCode);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new UserCRUDException(new RESTLetErrorHandler().handleServerError(re));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note: USERCRUDException is my own exception and not one of JAVA

Please help me resolve this problem which probably prevents returning the UUID from the server and thus my application isn't moving ahead.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Restlet uses under the hood a generic bean conversion to convert bean to representation (and representation to bean). So your problem depends on the converter you use.

I made a test with the extension `org.restlet.ext.jackson` (that contains such bean converter) and with version 2.2.1 of Restlet. My test bean is described below:

```
public class TestBean {
    private String name;
    private String message;
    private UUID uuid;

    (...)

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
}
```

and the following test server resource:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public TestBean ping() {
        TestBean bean = new TestBean();
        bean.setMessage("pong");
        bean.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I received the following content for a GET method:

```
{
    "name":"my name",
    "message":"my message",
    "uuid":"be9e5381-d5c9-4e45-b5c8-4af1f8bdca16"
}
```

Can you provide the converter you use? and the list of the Restlet dependencies you have in your application?

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I haven't used jackson in my code. Dependencies - ext . -fileupload, servlet, slf4j, xml. I hope thats all the info you need.

Comment: How do you serialize your bean? Can you give me more details about the signature of your server resource and related content in it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware about which converter we have used. Can you tell me how to find it?

Comment: I've included this 4 jars of restlet. 1.org.restlet.ext.fileupload.jar 2.org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar 3.org.restlet.ext.slf4j.jar 4. org.restlet.ext.xml.jar

Comment: I think that you should include a jar that contains a converter for bean (for example, org.restlet.ext.jackson)

Comment: Do you want to use an UUID within a bean?

Comment: After adding org.restlet.ext.jackson,  do I need to make any change in code? and I've not used object as a return type in just one method. I've 15-20 class which returns different type of objects.

Comment: No it's something under the hood in Restlet... The conversion representation / bean is managed internally by Restlet.

Comment: I'm getting following exception. 25 Mar 2015 19:28:20  INFO - ErrorStatusService.getStatus - throwable NOT instanceof DBCRUDException
25 Mar 2015 19:28:20  WARN - Exception or error caught in server resource
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
 at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter.create(JacksonConverter.java:94)
 at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter.toRepresentation(JacksonConverter.java:236)
 at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toRepresentation(ConverterService.java:321)